# Example of uninstaller routine to remove all custom theme options from wp_options

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, uninstallation

All of my theme's custom options are preceeded with "mytheme_" + option.

For example, mytheme_color1, mytheme_color2, mytheme_body_font_color, etc...

I'd like to create a plugin that uninstalls all of the items in wp_options where the option is preceeded with "mytheme_"

If you have a reference or example, please share it. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All of my theme's custom options are preceeded with "mytheme_" + option.

Not safe enough. Use [set_theme_mod()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_theme_mod), [get_theme_mod()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_theme_mod) and [remove_theme_mod()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_theme_mod) instead. You’ll find these and more related functions in `wp-includes/theme.php`.

Answer (score 1):

`DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name LIKE 'mytheme%'`